# Dynamic rectangles in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, dynamic

First I'm pretty new to Javascript, so sorry if my question comes across poorly.

I'm creating an application in Flash to help users calculate their electrical costs. Then I'm taking this figure and write it to an xml file.

Now I'm looking to open a webpage and show a google map, and there is a rectangle drawn over the map which is generated dynamically from the number generated earlier and stored in the xml file.

I'm completely lost as to places to turn on how to achieve this. I've gotten my map on to my page, and it scales 100% as I want it to, but I can't figure out the dynamic rectangle part at all. Any ideas or pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In this latest version](http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/xmlrect4.html), the XML file

```
<countries>
  <country name="USA" lat="40.0" lng="-100.0" width="30.0"/>
  <country name="France" lat="46.6" lng="2.7" width="10"/>
  <country name="Germany" lat="51.1" lng="10.1" width="20"/>
</countries>
```

is loaded as soon as the map tiles finish loading. I could not get the `getProjection` to be called correctly if I did not wait for tile loading to finish. The docs state that getting the projection needs the map to be initialized, and recommends listening for `projection_changed`. Both ways work yet I still feel listening to tiles_loaded is safer and if something goes wrong with the xml loading it will get called again if the map is zoomed or panned a noticeable amount.

```
  var map;
  var xmlLoaded = false;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', loadData);
  }

  function loadData() {
    if(!xmlLoaded) {
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "co2data.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        var countries = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("country");
        for(var i = 0, country; country = countries[i]; i++) {
          var name = country.getAttribute("name");

          var lat = parseFloat(country.getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(country.getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));

          // width is really an arbitrary unit, relative to CO2 tonnage.
          // equals the side of the drawn square.
          // it is measured in google maps points units.
          var width = parseFloat(country.getAttribute("width"));

          makeCO2Rect(name, point, width);
        }
        xmlLoaded = true;
      }
     });
    }
  }
```

The rectangle is defined by width in points (the whole world is 256x256 points), so some conversion is needed when assigning their centers to the more conventional LatLng.

```
  function rectParamsToBounds(point, width) {
    var ctrX = point.x;
    var ctrY = point.y;

    var swX = ctrX - (width/2);
    var swY = ctrY - (width/2);

    var neX = ctrX + (width/2);
    var neY = ctrY + (width/2);
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(swX, swY)),
        map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(neX, neY)));
  }
```

Finally, a rectangle is created with a country name that goes into a [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/) (using v1.1.5 here, you can hotlink to http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js though I prefer saving a local copy)

Since dragging a rectangle appears impossible, a marker in its center works as a handle. When it's dragged, the associated rectangle moves with it.

```
  function makeCO2Rect(name, point, width) {
    var rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: rectParamsToBounds(point, width)
    });

    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
      map: map,
      position: map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(point.x, point.y)),
      draggable: true,
      raiseOnDrag: false,
      labelContent: name,
      labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
      labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
      labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0}
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(event) {
      var newLatLng = event.latLng;
      var newPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(newLatLng);
      rect.setBounds(rectParamsToBounds(newPoint, width));
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Styling the labels need to be done both in the .labels CSS class and the constructor, and rectangles have options like stroke color, thickness, opacity, and fill color.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such an in-depth response!

Oops, didn't mean to post that yet :),

That looks like it would work, but my problem would be I will be dealing with a single number from the flash application. How would I convert this into longitude and latitude points ? How would that maintain a proper scale so that you can compare different numbers. (I'm not looking to create multiple outputs on the same map, but i plan on printing these or posting to facebook so people can see how they measure up against other users.)

Comment: @Quill Can you give an example of such a number from Flash? I don't get it. Is it a score? Does it really represent a world coordinate?Or post what your XML looks like in the question. Google maps needs a location to place a rectangle. Do you mean to place many rectangles side-by-side each to represent a person? If you change your question write another comment here so I get notified.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example of the XML code. That is from a different part of the project than I am working on. As far as I know it hasn't been figured out as of yet, I know this probably hampers anyone's ability to help me. Its a carbon footprint visualisation im looking for. So the flash application will tell the person how many tonnes of CO2 they output, and then im looking to create a rectangle to represent that area on a map, so they have an idea, based of a real world image of something they know of how big it actually is. So the figure I'll be receiving will be something like 9tonnes

Comment: @Quill Wait, is the map in the Flash application then? Even if not, I'm not sure how to move data from Flash to a Javascript page. What I suggest is outputting the country name with the volume in tonnes, with a map coordinate to match the country name. I can't help much further than this because I never made apps with Flash.

Comment: The flash application when the user has gone through it will open a browser page. I was hoping that before this it would write the users result to an XML file. When the browser opens the map reads the users footprint and displays an overlay of that size on the map. Once the page has opened for the user it wont change again. So say the users footprint is 1 tonne of CO2 per year, 1 tonne is 8.23m cubed. or with a 1 meter height, its a 23.14m squared rectangle. So what I want is to display a rectangle of that size on the page. I don' know if this helps any bit but again thanks for your time

Comment: I'm trying to put together a picture of how the parts fit. There's the very slim chance that two users finishing the Flash application at the same time will result in overwriting the data, otherwise it sounds like a good plan. (If you know PHP you could use URL variables and _GET, and would avoid this scenario). So, my plan would be: user completes Flash, the Flash app writes an XML in a fixed location and redirects to Javascript Google Map page, the Google map page reads the XML, and places a rectangle on the map.

Comment: That is exactly it! 2 people using it at the same time won't be an issue as it will be used from a sole location at this time, later i can worry about extending it :D

Comment: heh cheers :), so I can use the above code as a base to start working from for this do you think ?

Comment: No matter how new to JavaScript you are, can't you tell my code is awful? :) That is, I didn't write a XML reading component because I don't know what it looks like.

Comment: urrr I feel I should say yes of course I can to save some face, but no I really am that poor at javascript I couldn't tell it was poorly written lol. Either way though, cheers m8. XML reading component :D, at least I have name of some things to be googling now, whereas before; I know so little it's impossible to find how to do what I want without the key words or phrases :)

Comment: I'll try to write my own XML parsing code with a custom XML format. I should be the one to be ashamed for putting sloppy answers here. I'm being serious, I'll post again here when I'm done.

Comment: Heitor, I genuinely cannot thank you enough for the help you've given so far, from the bottom of my heart i really do appreciate any little help given, and thanks again!

Comment: I'm having fun :D Now I can't do much about the Flash part :( Oh and do you know how to convert meters to latitudes and longitudes? I might get this part wrong. I guess it would be ok if you don't need scientific precision. Thing is one deg. latitude becomes longer as you move towards a pole.

Comment: :-o i can't believe you already know more about this than I do, but that sort of precision isn't necessary though, as i want them to be able to move the map underneath, but hold the size of the rectangle so they can view it over different area's. That would require constant scaling if they were to go north or south, and thats uneeded

Comment: Alright finally got something presentable :) I'm using jQuery because I couldn't get the long version working. http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/xmlrect2.html (click on the load data button top left corner) The XML looks like this http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/co2data.xml the width is merely in latitude and longitude degrees (i.e. totally wrong). Sliding the rectangle/map is a new challenge! I'll have to think about that but now I'm leaving my computer for the day. See you!

Comment: Heitor you are a king amongst men, thank to so much for your help, have a great day!

Comment: @Quill I like my latest update, it'll be a lot more helpful to you. The only ugly part is a flag to check if the XML was already loaded (I updated my answer above with a brief explanation). http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/xmlrect4.html :)

Comment: Sorry Heitor, i thought i had already replied to this. Thank you again for going even further with this, you have REALLY helped me out with this, cant tell ya how far behind i would be without your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to place a rectangular shape on the map, you can create a `google.maps.Rectangle`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle). If you want to create a rectangular label on the map, you may be more interested in the InfoBox Utility Library[<sup>wiki-page</sup>](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox).

Comment: It's not a label i'm looking to create, its more a data visualisation. I want to take the number from the flash application and visually show people how large an area that is, on google maps. Cheers for the response though!

Comment: A rectangular shape was the first option in my answer; creating a label was the second. But pursue @Heitor's answer; it has _much more_ detail. +1 Heitor-

Comment: I have taken a look through the rectangle api doc, but unfortunately it seems to only point me towards creating a static rectangle, not one that would change depending on data written to an external file.

Comment: The `google.maps.Rectangle` class isn't static, it has a `setBounds` method that allows you to adjust the bounds as needed.